# Error in data.frame arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I get this really odd error on the following line:

```
updat = data.frame(Ranking=RankingRow[[1, "#"]], Ticker=RankingRow[[1, "Ticker"]], Name=RankingRow[[1, "Name"]],Updated=RankingRow[[1, "Updated"]], Percentage=RankingRow[[1, "Target Weight"]],ClosePrice=RankingRow[[1, "Close Price"]], buyOrSell="Sell",amount=porto[[row, "aantal"]])
```

Error:

```
    Error in data.frame(Ranking = RankingRow[[1, "#"]], Ticker = RankingRow[[1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

And glimpse(RankingRow) gives:

```
    Observations: 1
Variables: 15
$ `#`                    <int> 11
$ Ticker                 <chr> "AKAM"
$ Name                   <chr> "Akamai Technologies Inc Common"
$ Adj.Slope90            <dbl> 165.2
$ Adj.Slope125           <dbl> 135.29
$ Adj.Slope250           <dbl> 0
$ Avg.Slope.125.250      <dbl> 67.645
$ Sector                 <chr> "Technology"
$ Industry               <chr> "IT Services & Consulting"
$ `Max Gap`              <dbl> 13.69
$ `Target Weight`        <dbl> 5.55
$ `Stock Trend - SMA100` <int> 1
$ ATR                    <dbl> 1.22
$ Updated                <date> 2018-02-01
$ `Close Price`          <dbl> 67.56
```

I have seen other people who get the same error but i don't seem to have the same reason why i get it.
I anybody could point me the probably very obvious mistake I made I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: (1) It's a little weird to be using `[[` with two arguments, usually we'd use `[`. (2) Run each piece of the internal data frame call individually; one of them will be of length zero, possibly because you've misspelled a column name.

Comment: Well that did it, I misspelled one indeed I thought i checked it but apparently missed one. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of joran i could figure out what caused my error.
I run everything without the [[ ,  and as he said i misspelled a column name.

Comment: I awnsered my own question?

Comment: I dont need Any more clarification because the error is fixed.

Comment: if this solved the problem please mark as solution

Comment: i can't do that in the first 2 day